# GCC switch on enum, retain missing warning but use default

Tags: c++, gcc

Using GCC, if you `switch` on an `enum` value and one of the enums is missing a `case` statement a warning will be emitted. When you add a `default` item the warning will no longer be emitted, which makes sense in the general case.

Is there a way to use a `default` statement and still have a warning if not all the `enum` values are covered? Since my function may deal with impure input I'd like to cover the generic case but still get compiler warnings about missing an enum case.

Currently I end up assigning a default after the switch statement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[-Wswitch-enum](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wswitch_002denum-303), but unluckily only the most recent version supports this.

(You could of course simulate the behaviour that you want by using a goto outside the switch and omitting the default, but I would strongly advise against that, it's ugly and someone else reading your code would have a WTF experience.)

Comment: This sounds like it will turn it on for all switch statements. That is certainly not what I want: many cases only handle a handful of many enum values. I'd like a way that I can somehow enable on a per-switch basis.

Comment: Though I suppose with a newer GCC I might be able to use pragma push/pop to get this enabled for this piece of code.

Comment: Sadly, there is no way of enabling an option on a per-switch (or per-function) base, other than target and optimization options (for which "function specific option" pragmas exist). So if you only want this behaviour in some particular spots, you'll probably have no other choice but to go the "assign default value manually" way that you're going now. EDIT: Ah, you found those. Yes, but like I said, they work for optimization and target, but nothing else. I had wished many times they worked for more options.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: I believe that you can use it in pragma directives, something similar to `#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wswitch-enum"` could do the trick. Read about it [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)

Comment: Yes, those pragma's are what I meant. They are unfortunately also relatively new additions to GCC (that is, our distro doesn't have them yet). :(   EDIT: basically this answer with the comments would work with a newer version though, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6):

After reading the link from "David Rodríguez - dribeas", I thought it would be helpful to summarise the options listed there.

There are two ways to do this - either turn the messages about missing enum cases on for all `switch` statements, then disable it for the ones you don't care about, or leave it at the default and force the errors on for those `switch` statements you really care about.

**Option 1: Warnings for all, mark some as silent**

First, add `-Wswitch-enum` to your compiler flags, so that all `switch` statements, even ones with a `default` clause, will have warnings generated if an enum is not handled.

Then, for those `switch` statements where you want the `default` case to take care of things and don't want to see warnings, wrap the `switch` statement like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch-enum"

switch () {
    ...
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This will temporarily disable the `-Wswitch-enum` flag (hiding the warnings about missing enum cases) just for that case statement.

**Option 2: Only warn when flagged to do so**

Since the default GCC behaviour is to hide warnings when a `default` clause is present, the compiler flags don't need to be changed for this option.

Instead, for those `switch` statements that include a `default` clause, but you still want to see warnings about missing enum cases, wrap the `switch` like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wswitch-enum"

switch () {
    ...
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This temporarily enables the `-Wswitch-enum` flag between the `push` and `pop` lines, causing messages about missing enum cases to be displayed even when a `default` clause is present.  You can change the word `warning` to `error` if you want compilation to fail on a missing case.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the issue is more at the `enum` level.

What I mean is that you should first validate your input (ie make sure that it does indeed map into a real enum) and only once validated, should you use the enum, in which case the default becomes redundant.

In order to validate the input, a *simple* solution I use is to create the enum through a macro which will also automatically generate *converting* functions: from/to `string`, from `int` (or whatever).

For example:

```
DEFINE_ENUM_DETAILED(SomeEnum, int, (Foo, 0, "Foo")(Bar, 1, "Bar"));
```

Could generate:

```
struct SomeEnum {
  enum { Foo = 0, Bar = 1 } type;

  type FromString(std::string const& s) {
    if (s == "Foo") { return Foo; }
    if (s == "Bar") { return Bar; }
    assert(0 && "SomeEnum::FromString - unknown value");
  }

  std::string ToString(type e) {
    switch(e) {
    case Foo: return "Foo";
    case Bar: return "Bar";
    }
  }

  type FromIntegral(int i) {
    switch(i) {
    case Foo: return Foo;
    case Bar: return Bar;
    }
    assert(0 && "SomeEnum::FromIntegral- unknown value");
  }
};
```

It's the only way I have found to generate this *easily* (though the string conversion is here a bit simplified here).

Another solution would be to use a script to generate the source code from an alternative file.

**EDIT:** Having the switch operating and validating

The simple answer is (like I did above) to let the program flow out of the switch instead of using a default clause. This is possible if normal flow (when falling into a `case`) does not end up falling out of the switch.

```
switch(event) {
case Foo: {
  // bla
  return 0;
}
case Bar: {
  return 0;
}
}

unreachable("should never have got there");
```

Comment: Enums are coming on the wire in a binary format. In general we trust the input to be correct (not an external API) but need to be defensive just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: I agree with the defensive strategy (corruptions, bugs, ...). It does not change the heart of my answer: validate first, and then you can use the enum without any worry that there is garbage in (just use abort outside the switch).

Comment: Well, basically I want my switch to be operative and validating. My `default` clause is the one that catches an invalid definition (and it usually throws an exception). I'd like to avoid having an extra switch just to validate as it gives redundant code to maintain.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: I've edited my answer to reflect this use case. The simple idea is to refactor the switch to a function of its own in order to use a `return` to prevent the flow from falling out of the switch, this way you can consider that falling out of the switch is an error condition (that would normally be handled through `default`) and still have the compiler warn if there is a missing `case`. How you deal with the error is up to you.

Comment: This is really the only response that answers the question. The macro enum version is a bit over the top in my opinion (for the general case, but may be useful for things like human readable serialization), but having all handled switch cases return (or `goto`, or set a valid flag, etc.) on valid values is really the only way to accomplish both goals of having the compiler verify all known cases are handled, and have a place to handle garbage input.

Comment: Suppose you have a legacy code base with hundreds, or thousands of switches with default statements. You just want to know which ones don't handle some enum cases, without editing them all.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of today, neither gcc nor llvm can detect you are not comparing all the values of an `enum`in a `switch` if you include a `default` switch.

Comment: they do, unless you specify a `default` clause, in which case you indicate that it makes sense to have a default.

Answer (score 0):

One reason would be that you must be able to write warning-free code without breaking your back. If, for example, you have an enum with 100 constants, then you would have to list each and every one of them in every switch statement, even if you only needed to inspect a handful of them, if the warning should work as you suggested.

Comment: I'm aware of this and do rely on this as well. In some cases my default really is a *normal* situation. In the cases I mention above the default is a defensive bit of code. I want distinct warning behaviour in each case.